# Lubuntu 20.04LTS

Tags: lubuntu

I upgraded from Lubuntu 18.04LTS after months of 'upgrade'-pestering by unwittingly pressing the 'upgrade' button that comes with it and then decided to go along with it.

My Dell Optiplex 7010 is now not VERY slow, but noticeably slower than when it was run on 18.04LTS. Does anyone know what needs to be done to make the Lubuntu 20.04LTS run it faster, if at all?

Comment: The release notes state rather clearly a *fresh install* should be performed. Yes your Ubuntu base allows upgrade; but issues were warned of.  See https://lubuntu.me/focal-released/ where it states "*Note, due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04 or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please do a fresh install.*"   The issues varied on what packages you had installed (broken, imperfect etc..)

Comment: Lubuntu 18.04 LTS or LXDE used GTK2 libs & applications. Modern Lubuntu uses LXQt (ie. Qt5) as GTK2 is *deprecated*, so different apps are *lighter* in Qt5 than were used in prior GTK2 releases. If you're using old apps; the effect on system performance will *decline* unless you've the resources (esp. RAM) to reduce the impact of having multiple libs that do the same thing co-exist in RAM.  I QA-tested 18.04 & later & differences are minimal (esp. if you don't waste resources by choosing carefully; and that included 1GB ram & single-core cpu devices up to Lubuntu 19.04; 2GB & dual-core 19.10+)

Comment: You've also not made clear if you're asking about Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using LXDE Desktop, or Lubuntu 20.04 LTS (ie. LXQt)

Comment: Apologies. Come to think about it, I was aware of the 'UPGRADE' situation and did conduct a clean install. (It was nearly two months ago, and so I forgot to mention that I did come across warnings and recommendations favouring the 'clean install'). So yes, after the clean install the system is stable, but is much slower from other Lubuntu installations. 
Up until this version (i.e. Lubuntu 20.04LTS) I would encourage people to switch to Lubuntu from Windows, but not now. I've been a heavy user of Lubuntu since 13.04 version - now using now Lubuntu 20.04 LTS (ie. LXQt).

Answer (score 1):

The release notes state rather clearly a fresh install should be performed. Yes your Ubuntu base allows upgrade; but issues on upgrade were warned of. See https://lubuntu.me/focal-released/ where it states

> "Note, due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop
> environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04
> or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken
> system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please
> do a fresh install.

The issues varied on what packages you had installed.  Yes it's possible (*the box I'm using now is an upgraded box*) but whilst some boxes have minor issues, some are not so (*it took me 2-3 weeks of fixing issues before I was happy on this box, on some boxes I was happy first boot or with only minor fixes/tweaks*)

Lubuntu 18.04 LTS was a LXDE system using GTK2 *libs* & applications. Modern Lubuntu uses LXQt (ie. Qt5) as GTK2 is *deprecated*, so different apps are lighter in Qt5 than were used in prior GTK2 releases.

If you're using old apps; the effect on system performance will decline unless you've the resources (esp. RAM) to reduce the impact of having multiple libs that do the same thing co-exist in RAM. I QA-tested 18.04 & later & differences are minimal (esp. if you don't waste resources by choosing carefully; and that included 1GB ram & single-core cpu devices up to Lubuntu 19.04; 2GB & dual-core 19.10+)

If you wanted to continue using LXDE; preparation (ie. making your system a non-Lubuntu, but pure LXDE one) should have been performed **prior to upgrade** (so LXQt & *modern* Lubuntu configs were not installed).

If you want to use LXQt & have a *resource limited machine* you should adjust your use of the system and not use your old apps that made sense on LXDE, but not LXQt.

If that's your issue though; it's unclear, as you've not indicated if you're trying to still use

- Lubuntu (ie. LXQt)
- LXDE or your older desktop environment & no longer wish to use Lubuntu
- your issue relates to the *unsupported* upgrade; though most issues are minor & petty & those generally didn't impact performance; though some may (*why the upgrade was unsupported & the prepared documentation on the upgrade steps was never fully published*)

FYI:  The last Lubuntu 20.04.3 release notes no longer mention the *upgrade from 18.04* as *unsupported* or to be avoided; as Lubuntu 18.04 LTS had already reached it's *[end of life](https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/)*, but prior release notes included the warning.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments, Lubuntu 18.04 should not be upgraded because the desktop environment has changed from LXDE in 18.94 to LXQt in later releases.

To resolve the performance problems with your installation, you should cleanly reinstall Lubuntu 20.04.